# toggle on/off an event listener with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a porblem with my code and I'm pretty confused why is that happening! here is what it going on:

I've got several columns (with 'col-1-2' class) which are assigned a function (miniPage) for on(mouseup) event, whichever you click on, its width expands and other columns collapse, and cycle continues by clicking other columns.
I want to remove event listener from expanded column, instead assign another function (miniPage2) to a button element (with 'call-to-action' class) inside this column.
I added 2 event listener for both my classes ('col-1-2' and 'call-to-action') with respective functions, then manage listeners inside functions. my code works fine unless I don't add miniPage2 into my code, but somehow it does'nt work when I add miniPage2, and it seems that both functions (miniPage and miniPage2) will take action even when miniPage is not supposed to so. here is my code:

```
    $(function() {
        var isDragging = false;
        $(".col-1-2").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
                isDragging = true;
                $(window).off("mousemove")
            })
        })
        .on("mouseup", function() {
            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;
            $(window).off("mousemove");
            if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
        })
    });

    $(function() {
        var isDragging = false;
        $(".call-to-action").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
                isDragging = true;
                $(window).off("mousemove")
            })
        })
        .on("mouseup", function() {
            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;
            $(window).off("mousemove");
            if (!wasDragging) {miniPage2();}
        })
    });


    function miniPage(activeTab) {
        var arz;
        arz = $(".col-1-2");
        var elmnt = $("#" + activeTab);
        var isDragging = false;
        if (elmnt.prop('style')['width'] != "80%") {
            arz.animate({width: "20%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
            elmnt.animate({width: "80%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
            arz.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup").on("mousedown", function() {
                $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
                    isDragging = true;
                    $(window).off("mousemove")
                })
            })
            .on("mouseup", function() {
                var wasDragging = isDragging;
                isDragging = false;
                $(window).off("mousemove");
                if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
            })
            elmnt.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup");
        } else {
            arz.animate({width: "50%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
            }
        }
    }


    function miniPage2() {
        var arz;
        arz = $(".col-1-2");
            arz.animate({width: "50%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
            arz.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
                isDragging = true;
                $(window).off("mousemove")
            })
        })
            .on("mouseup", function() {
                var wasDragging = isDragging;
                isDragging = false;
                $(window).off("mousemove");
                if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
            })
        }
    }
```

```js
$(function() {
      var isDragging = false;
      $(".col-1-2").on("mousedown", function() {
       $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
        isDragging = true;
        $(window).off("mousemove")
       })
      })
      .on("mouseup", function() {
       var wasDragging = isDragging;
       isDragging = false;
       $(window).off("mousemove");
       if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
      })
     });
     $(function() {
      var isDragging = false;
      $(".call-to-action").on("mousedown", function() {
       $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
        isDragging = true;
        $(window).off("mousemove")
       })
      })
      .on("mouseup", function() {
       var wasDragging = isDragging;
       isDragging = false;
       $(window).off("mousemove");
       if (!wasDragging) {miniPage2();}
      })
     });
     
       function miniPage(activeTab) {
      var arz;
         arz = $(".col-1-2");
        var elmnt = $("#" + activeTab);
            var isDragging = false;
         if (elmnt.prop('style')['width'] != "80%") {
           arz.animate({width: "20%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
             arz.removeClass("showContent hideContent");
             arz.addClass("hideFeature miniPage");
             elmnt.removeClass("hideFeature miniPage");
                   elmnt.addClass("hideContent");
        elmnt.animate({width: "80%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
        elmnt.delay(2000).queue(function(){elmnt.addClass("showContent").dequeue();});
        arz.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup").on("mousedown", function() {
               $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
                isDragging = true;
                $(window).off("mousemove")
               })
              })
              .on("mouseup", function() {
               var wasDragging = isDragging;
               isDragging = false;
               $(window).off("mousemove");
               if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
              })
              elmnt.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup");
          } else {
            arz.animate({width: "50%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
                arz.removeClass("showContent");
                   arz.delay(2000).queue(function(){arz.removeClass("hideFeature hideContent").dequeue();});
          }
     }
     
     function miniPage2() {
         var arz;
         arz = $(".col-1-2");
            var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            var isDragging = false;
           arz.animate({width: "50%"},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
               arz.removeClass("showContent");
                arz.delay(2000).queue(function(){arz.removeClass("hideFeature hideContent").dequeue();});
                arz.off("mousedown mousemove mouseup").on("mousedown", function() {
           $(window).on("mousemove", function() {
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).off("mousemove")
           })
          })
             .on("mouseup", function() {
              var wasDragging = isDragging;
           isDragging = false;
           $(window).off("mousemove");
           if (!wasDragging) {miniPage(this.id);}
          })
     }
```

```css
.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#id1 {
 background-color: red;
}
#id2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.call-to-action {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.col-1-2.showContent .call-to-action {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div id="id1" class="col-1-2">
    <div class="call-to-action">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="id2" class="col-1-2">
    <div class="call-to-action">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

P.S1: The main problem here is that my miniPage triggered when it's not suppose to (when I click the button, first miniPage2 will trigger, then miniPage2), I know it's fine, cause if I comment miniPage2 it will not trigger anymore and just do nothing, but somehow when I add miniPage2 something will break and I don't have any idea what is it and why is that? I'm pretty confused, any help would be appreciated! <3

P.S2: try to ignore typos, i tried to minify code, so maybe I miss something.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52812592/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan ok, started creating one, but since its my first time making one, may take some times!

Answer (score 0):

Why is MainPage2 `arz` referencing `.col-1-2` instead of `.call-to-action` 
Additionally, in your `.off` events clear arz and elmnt

Comment: miniPage2 is referencing to 'col-1-2' because it wants to change column'd width, not button's! I find out that if you add same event to an element make it to call the function twice, so whenever I want to add event, i will remove all events before it, then add it again! and finally remove event from elmnt, so the expanded element doesnt have an event listener